# Graphics and panel size

Tags: graphics, manipulate

Consider the following snippet:

```
  DynamicModule[{},
   Manipulate[
    Graphics[
     Translate[
      GeometricTransformation[
       {Blue, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
       {{scx, 0}, {0, scy}}],
      Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1]],
    {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1},
    {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1},
    {{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1},
    {{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want a stable, fixed, panel in which the polygons are displayed, thus independent from the slider values. Applying the `PlotRange-> option` to the `Graphics` function in the example above doesn't work as expected.

**Question: How should I set and fix the panel size?**

Comment: I am getting the error `Affine transform {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}} should be one of the forms {{{xx, yx}, {xy, yy}}, {tx, ty}}; {{xx, yx}, {yy, yy}}; or {tx, ty}.`

Comment: If I put `width` and `height` all the way to the left, and use `PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-1, 2}}` the `x` and `y` sliders appear stable.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with `Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}]` ?  The output doesn't appear to match the syntax of `Translate`.

Comment: Adding `PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}` to `Graphics` works for me.

Comment: @Heike for reference, do you get the error I did?  Has that changed in v8?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't get an error. In version 8 you can specify a list of vectors over which to translate the object. It's similar to `Translate[gr, #]& /@ (Tuples[...] - 1)`.

Comment: With Heike's adjustment this works just fine for me.  I think you've made a mistake in your code; please check it.

Comment: OK, add PlotRange and set all sliders to max. then set width to 3. The panel size changes. The question is about avoiding this.

Comment: I'm still not seeing it.  What happens if you use this?: `DynamicModule[{}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[Translate[
      GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
        Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, {{scx, 0}, {0, 
         scy}}], #] & /@ (Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1), 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 6}}], {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 
   1}, {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}, {{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 
   1}, {{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]]`

Comment: Works different than my code above. It is stable but the square is reduced to 1/5 th of the size or so. Resizing should only occur when there is not enough space in the initial panel area.

Comment: That's not making sense to me; describe how it is to be both stable and dynamic at the same time?

Comment: Imagine a square with width / height = 1. Display that initially, so it fills the panel. If I reduce the size of the square, the panel maintains it size but the square becomes smaller. If I add a square the squares are shown at half size. - The panel size/width, initially, is the standard. ( I may not be able to reply anymore today, this can wait. Thanks for the help sofar. )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is simply `ImageSize -> {Xpx, Ypx}` option. It will fix your outer graphics frame to be displayed as X pixels by Y pixels, re-sizing graphics objects to fit into it. The approximate shape of that frame can be seen from the orange selection line when you click on the graphics as shown below. The figure below shows the action of "adding squares" as you described in the comment to your main question.

```
DynamicModule[{}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[Translate[
    GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
      Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, {{scx, 0}, {0, 
       scy}}], Tuples[{Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1], 
   ImageSize -> 400 {1, 1}], {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 
   1}, {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1}, {{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 
   1}, {{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]]
```

[image]

BTW, `DynamicModule` wrapped around serves no purpose in this particular case. I just kept it to preserve your code as much as possible.

Comment: YES! This is what I was looking for. I can fix my issues now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, adding `PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}` works for me, so I'm just assuming you're looking for possible alternatives.

The answers based on `ImageSize` and `ContentSize` work fine if you know what the output size in units of printer's points is supposed to be. But if you instead want to specify a fixed size in the units that you're actually using for your rectangles in the manipulate, I would suggest a different approach.

Simply add an invisible rectangle of the desired fixed dimensions to the list of graphics objects. Here I inserted `{Transparent, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}]}` before the dynamically variable polygons:

```
DynamicModule[{}, Manipulate[
  Graphics[{{Transparent, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}]},
    Translate[
     GeometricTransformation[
      {Blue, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
      {{scx, 0}, {0, scy}}
      ],
     Tuples[
       {Range[wi], Range[he]}] - 1]}
   ],
  {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}, {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 
   1}, {{wi, 1, "width"}, 1, 5, 1}, {{he, 1, "heigth"}, 1, 5, 1}]]
```

[image: panel]

Answer (score 5):

Please try this simplified example and tell me if it works as expected.  The key feature is the option `ContentSize`:

```
DynamicModule[{},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[
   GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, {{scx, 0}, {0, scy}}]],
  {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}, {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1},
  ContentSize -> {400, 400}
 ]
]
```

Or combined with `PlotRange`:

```
DynamicModule[{},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[
   GeometricTransformation[{Blue, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, {{scx, 0}, {0, 
      scy}}], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
  {{scx, 1, "x scale"}, 0, 1}, {{scy, 1, "y scale"}, 0, 1},
  ContentSize -> {400, 400}
 ]
]
```

Comment: You left out the Translate and that's exactly what messed it up. I understand the noise now.

Comment: @ndroock1 sorry, your code didn't work in version 7; I tried.